# WinActivate does not work as expected. Re-activating focus to the starting window

Tags: autohotkey

I am having some serious struggles fully grasping the control on activating windows and forcing their focus and foremost position.

In order to debug a larger script I made a separate script to test the use of WinActivate and again I am observing frustrating behaviour as it either all together ignores the title I have defined or is failing in some other way. In the smaller test script I am simply requesting that the window in which the hotkey was triggered be set as active after another action, specifically an input box

Below is the simple code for testing:

```
F10::

    SetTitleMatchMode, 1
    DetectHiddenWindows, Off

    WinGetTitle, startTitle, A
    msgbox % "Start Title = <" . startTitle . ">"

    ;WinActivate, startTitle

    inputbox, mode, Test box,  Testing,,260,160
    sleep 500
    WinActivate,  startTitle

Return
```

This code does not properly activate the starting window. For example I execute the hotkey in an empty notepad window and upon submitting blank into the input box the focus becomes notepad++ on my second monitor. The second time I press the hotkey from within notepad (or another application) notepad does not lose focus. In a third execution I begin from notepad again and after the input box appears I switch the focus to another window. I again submit blank to the inputbox but that new window remains the focus and notepad is not activated or brought to the foremost position.

**Can someone please explain to me what is going on with WinActivate?**

I was having similar frustration with unexpected results making a windows script host file and I think I must be missing some fundamental detail in windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to activate a window that start with the literal text "startTitle".
You forgot(?) to either enter expression syntax with `%` or use the legacy way of referring to a variable `%startTitle%` (please don't use legacy).

Extra stuff:
You shouldn't specify `SetTitleMatchMode` and `DetectHiddenWindows` inside your hotkey statement. There is no need (unless there actually is) to set those every time you hit the hotkey. Just specify them at the top of your script once.
Both of them are useless for you though, below I'll show why. Also `DetectHiddenWindows` is already off by default.

`WinGetTitle` is not good to use for this. What you actually want to do is get the hwnd of the window you wish by using e.g. [`WinExist()`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinExist.htm).
And then refer to the window by its hwnd. Much better than working with window titles, and *impossible* to match the wrong window as well. To refer to a window by its hwnd, you specify `ahk_id` followed by the hwnd on a [WinTitle](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm) parameter.

And lastly, the concatenation operator `.` is redundant. Of course you may prefer to use it, but in case you didn't know, it can just be left out.

Here's your revised code:

```
F10::
    _HWND := WinExist("A")
    MsgBox, % "Start hwnd = <" _HWND ">"
    InputBox, mode, Test box,  Testing,,260,160
    Sleep, 500
    WinActivate, % "ahk_id " _HWND
Return
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. This morning I was thinking the literal title is likely an unreliable way
• I did not know that it was not expanding the variable in the statement, this will need some more reading on my part for me to grasp the context differences
• The title match modes were not there originally but added as my executions failed and I was trying new things. I will likely still need to include these in the real script just as a redundant operation. Would these be active in the scope of the hotkey and revert afterwards?
• Thanks for . tip
I will test and mark correct TY

Comment: Yeah, legacy vs expression syntax can be a bit confusing when you're getting started. Reading [this](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Language.htm) might help. And no, they would not only be active in the scope of the hotkey. If you want to change them temporarily, you could get the current value with the corresponding `A_ ...` variable (`A_DetectHiddenWindows` and `A_TitleMatchMode`) and change back to it at the end of your hotkey or whatever.